# How do I freeze a specific gem into a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My question is very similar to [How do I freeze gems into a Rails 3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411522/how-do-i-freeze-gems-into-a-rails-3-application), but I only want to freeze a single modified gem. The answers to that question seem to result in bundling all the application's gems.

In case it's relevant, I need to do this so the modified gem gets installed on Heroku.

I checked the [bundle-install doc](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html) but it didn't seem to address this situation. I can't imagine it's that uncommon, though. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to those who answered the question with related approaches, I ended up going with the approach mentioned in [this sister question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684447/how-to-use-bundle-package-on-my-edited-gem/7686000#7686000). For the sake of clarity, this is what I did:

1. Repackage modified gem as its own gem. This takes a little finagling but is described well in the [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/). Move said gem into your source directory (I used `vendor/gems`)
2. In the project's Gemfile, point to the location of the new gem:

   `gem "modified_gem", :path => "vendor/gems/modified_gem"`
3. Add new gem to version control, make sure `bundle install` isn't messed up with funky settings (e.g. `--local`), and cross your fingers.

Someone also mentioned that it's possible to mix in changes to the gem instead of overriding source files. I don't know anything more about this technique except that it should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Bundler is going to freeze all of them, and the idea is that you want to freeze not only a single gem, but the collection of gems that produced a working copy of your app.

That being said, on your local dev machine, you can do `bundle update [name of gem]` and it will update just that one gem to the latest version **within the restrictions specified in your Gemfile**, which also updates your `Gemfile.lock`, which effectively updates just that one gem on Heroku when you next deploy.

Comment: Hm, I tried both `bundle update gdata` and `bundle update gdata vendor/gems` (gdata is obviously the gem I need to modify), and both commands simply updated the gem in-place, overwriting my modified version. Given that this is the most upvoted answer, I must be missing something.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but I suspect that the correct answer here is the one from @tadman, and that normalocity didn't read your question carefully enough - no offence intended guys ...

Comment: Hey, if I'm wrong, I'm wrong - popular answers aren't always correct. I upvoted tadman's answer after reading through it again.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bundler`, which is the default for Rails 3, you can always fork the gem to your own git repository and add that definition to your `Gemfile` with whatever location it can be found at:

```
gem 'thegem', :git => 'git://github.com/cloned_to_me/thegem.git'
```

Another option is to use `bundle package` to save copies of the gems in `vendor/cache`. These can then be later installed using `bundle install --local` according to [the documentation](http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html).

This is the closest thing to the Rails 2 "freeze" method, but has the added advantage of saving the gems before they are installed, not after, avoiding any platform-specific problems as was the case previously.

Comment: Trying out your second option first: `bundle package` appears to work but—on closer inspection—it doesn't actually bundle my *changes*. I've verified that the version specified in `bundle show gdata` has my patch, but the version cached by `bundle package` is the unmodified version of the gem. [The bundle-package doc](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html) states that it only operates on .gem files (so not the installed gem directory?). Any want to freeze my specific version?

Comment: Also, it looks like [Github no longer supports gem building](https://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct) so I'm not going to go that route, and [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler#readme) (one of their recommended replacements) pushes automatically to RubyGems, which I'm not ready to do at this point, given that I'm a Ruby rookie.

Comment: p.s. Added the question above as a [proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684447/how-to-use-bundle-package-on-my-edited-gem), so if anyone answers here you might want to answer there as well to get proper credit :)

Comment: Pushing gems to rubygems.org has never been easier, so I wouldn't be too shy about it. All you really have to do is register and come up with a unique name for your gem. You can also have a private gem repository if you'd rather not publish it.

Comment: A word of caution to those using `bundle install --local`: doing so will update the default setting for bundle so all future `bundle install` commands will use the `--local` switch. You can reverse this setting with `bundle install --system`