# How to use bundle package on my edited gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to freeze a particular gem (with my edits) so I can push the modified version to Heroku. Per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682186/how-do-i-freeze-a-specific-gem-into-a-rails-3-application/7682354#7682354), I'm using `bundle package` to save copies of my existing gems into `vendor/cache`, but on closer inspection, it turns out this bundles the original server version of the gem, not my version.

I've verified that the files specified in `bundle show gdata` include my edits, which I thought would point the bundler to that version. The [bundle-package doc](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html) states that it only operates on .gem files (so not the installed gem directory?).

How can I freeze my particular version of the gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your modified gem into a folder like `vendor/gems`, and then point to that version in your Gemfile:

```
gem "modified_gem", :path => "vendor/gems/modified_gem"
```

And don't forget to check `vendor/gems` into version control.

Sorry for the brevity of this answer, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't seem to work. Have tried about every conceivable path option, including with/without trailing slash at the various directory levels. I get the error `Source does not contain any versions of 'gdata (>= 0)'`
Is this because I copied the uncompressed module, not a packaged .gem file? (And what would be the point of having to repackage it?)

Comment: @Dan - Make sure that you have a `gdata.gemspec` file that bundler can find in vendor/gems/gdata.

Comment: Thanks, bricked. For those watching at home, you have to make your own gem, not just copy the source directory. Also, I got messed up when, during the course of human events, I used `bundle install --local`. I was unaware that this set the default for all future `bundle install` operations to install locally as well. Reset this with `bundle install --system`.