# Install Rails Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In my company the production servers aren't connected to internet, so when we try to put our rails apps in those servers I can't make it woks because obviously the can't bundle the gems, My question is, can I distribute the gems inside my app?

Comment: your production servers are most likely connected to some sort of tool distro server.. if you have one, then put the gems on that/those server(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bundler to install your gems to the rails application vendor/gems directory:

```
$ bundle install vendor/gems
```

Alternately:

```
$ bundle package
```

References:
[How do I freeze gems into a Rails 3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411522/how-do-i-freeze-gems-into-a-rails-3-application)
[bundler install](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html)
[bundle package](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_package.html)

Comment: So, this commands copy all the gems in vendor/gems? I don't need run bundle install in my production servers?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run your own internal gem server at your company. Copy just the gems your company uses to your gem server, as well as any gems developed internally. In your app's gemfile, just add source to use it:

```
source "http://rubygems.my_example_company.com"
```

It can be as easy as running 'gem server' on the gem server, or using something like the Gem in a Box project. See http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/ for more information on setting it up.