# Freezing Rails gem versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I am trying to freeze my Rails gem version as, day by day, some or the other gem version gets updated and sometimes I need to update the code.

I tried `rake rails:freeze:gems` but this gave me error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:freeze:gems'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This locks and then caches the gems into ./vendor/cache.

```
$ bundle package
```

[Refer this link](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_package.html)

Answer (score 0):

`rake rails:freeze:gems` is an old Rails 2 way of doing it. I think you want to use Bundler's `bundle install vendor/gems`

"[How do I freeze gems into a Rails 3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411522/how-do-i-freeze-gems-into-a-rails-3-application)" seem to answer it better.