# Cannot freeze gem when trying to deploy to "A Small Orange"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to deploy my website to "A Small Orange" web hosting, and I have never done this before. Their instructions tell me I should freeze my app gems first before uploading, however I keep getting the error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:freeze:gems'
```

whenever I run the command:

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

I installed Capistrano as suggested and also did some research and found that I should run:

```
bundle package
```

which I did, however, I still have had no luck.

Does anyone know how I can deploy an application successfully?

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974904/freezing-rails-gem-versions?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The rake task `rake rails:freeze:gems` has been removed from Rails since Rails 3, given `Bundler` has become widely adpopted. The preferred way to bundle your project gems is now to use [Bundler `package` command](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_package.html).

```
$ bundle package
```

This command must be run in the target server, immediately after the code has been deployed.